# measure of "support of measure"

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space. Let $\mathcal{B}(T)$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X,\mathcal{B}(T))$.

The definition of the support of measure is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)

My question is that does the following equality hold?

> $$\mu(\mbox{supp}(\mu)) =\mu(X)$$

(I believe $\mbox{supp}(\mu) \subseteq X$)

If yes, then why?  If not, under what condition (about the measure) this will hold?

I am also a bit confused with such question and the condition if $\mu$ is a Lebesgue measure or a probability measure. Can anyone please give me a complete explanation of it?

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article you linked? Your questions are answered there.

Comment: Under the "Properties" and "Examples" sections. In the latter, there is an explicit example of a measure $\mu$ on a space $X$ for which $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Jason I saw it. If $A\subseteq X\ \mbox{supp}(\mu)$, then $\mu(A)=0$

Comment: I think this should hold when you define a measure on a separable space.

Comment: @sleevechen This is true if $X$ is Hausdorff and $\mu$ is a Radon measure, but not in general.

Comment: @Jason: Ah that's clever. It's because compact in hausdorff implies closed and radon measure implies inner regular i.e $\mu(A)$ becomes equal to the measure of the largest closed subset contained in $A$. This is precisely what the measure of the support is.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Just want to ask more: I am reading a paper, and the underlying topology should be Zariski Topology. (since $X$ is from a simple semialgebraic constraints) Does this equality still hold?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know. I could think about it, but I have no intuition for it at the moment.